# Electron: Use same singleton in main and renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, singleton, ipc

I'm attempting to create a singleton class that works in both the main and renderer processes, but I'm not sure what the best way of going about it is.

For example, I have a class which handles storing data:

```js
class Prefs {
    constructor() {
        this.prefsCache = // Load the prefs from a json file into the cache
    }

    set(key, value) {
        this.prefsCache[key] = value
        // Also save the prefs to disk here
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.prefsCache[key]
    }
}

export default new Prefs()
```

This works great in a single process, but if the class is required in the main and renderer, the cache will become out of sync the minuet a preference is changed since each process has a different instance.

It looks like the solution is to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), but I can't find an elegant solution for it. Here I create two different classes. PrefsMain handles saving and storing the data, and PrefsRenderer would communicate to the PrefsMain:

```js
class PrefsMain {
    constructor() {
        ipcMain.on('set-prefs-value', (event, key, newValue) => {
            this.set(key, newValue)
        })
    }

    set(key, value) {
        // ...
    }
}

class PrefsRenderer {
    set(key, newValue) {
        ipcRenderer.sendSync('set-prefs-value', key, newValue)
    }
}
```

Doing something like above works, but in reality, I have multiple singletons each with 20 or so methods. It seems like a lot of extra code needs to get written to accomplish it this way.

The other solution I found was to use electron's remote module:

```js
const Prefs = require('electron').remote.require('./prefs.js')
```

This also works, but it looks like the remote module [is going to be deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-8-0#deprecation-of-remote-module-starting-in-electron-9), so I'd rather not do it this way.

Is there a better solution for this? How can I elegantly create a singleton class that can be used in both the main and renderer processes, without having to create a duplicate IPC handler class for each?

Comment: cant you use `electron-settings` package for this? ,This logic is already implemented

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create two separate classes.

Just have a single `Prefs` class.

And then for your renderer to set or get things from the `Prefs` singleton, you would add ipc handlers to your main process:

```
ipcMain.on("setIntoPrefs", (event, key, value) => {
    prefsInstance.set(key, value);
});

ipcMain.handle("getPrefsValue", (event, key) => prefsInstance.get(key));
```

And your renderer would do:

```
ipcRenderer.send("setIntoPrefs", key, val);

const val = await ipcRenderer.invoke("getPrefsValue", key);
```

Comment: What if my singleton is not as simple, and has something like 20+ methods to manage a database? Do I have to write 20+ ipc event handlers to handle each one? If so, not only is it laborious, but also limited in terms of extensibility.

Comment: @Nicholas if the methods are somewhat related, you could have a single channel for a number of the methods and one of the args you pass is the specific action you want to do. But yes, you do need some IPC between the processes. Whether or not it's a single channel or several is up to you